# PopOS 20 MongoDB installation - mongodb-org-tools error

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-20.04

I am getting the following error trying to install the MongoDB tools on my Pop!_OS machine:

> mongodb-org-tools : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not installable

Any suggestions?

**Commands I Used**

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org-tools
```

**Verification of Pop version:**

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Pop!_OS"
VERSION="20.04 LTS"
```

**What I Tried**

- Using a backports solution (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378644/how-to-install-mongodb-3-4-in-debian-stretch-9))
- Instruction Set 1 [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)
- Instruction Set 2 [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-and-use-mongodb-on-ubuntu-2004/)

Comment: Why are you installing 3.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi,

You are using a **list file for MongoDB** to Ubuntu 16.04(Xenial).

Try to use the list for Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal):

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list
```

font: [MongoDB Community](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)